# Day number as a feature in Linear regression

Tags: time-series, linear-regression, time

**Goal** - To train a Linear regression model for climatic studies.

**Planned features**: - Temperatures, Latitude, Longitude, Day Number (1st February = 32)

Would it be correct to include day number like that?

**Can we assume ordinality in day numbers?** 2nd January isn't greater than 1st January in any way, so would it be correct to put 2nd January as 2 and 1st January as 1.

How can we have a day number feature keeping this in mind? Or something that would let us control which date for which we want to predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not correct to assume ordinality in day numbers in this context. Day number (i.e., the number of days since the beginning of the year) is not a meaningful feature for predicting temperature or other climatic variables.

One way to incorporate the date into your model is to use the month and year as separate features. For example, you could use two separate categorical variables: one for the month (e.g., January, February, etc.) and one for the year. This would allow you to control which date you want to predict for.

Alternatively, you could use a continuous variable for the date, such as the number of days since a reference date (e.g., 1/1/1970). This would allow you to capture any trends or patterns in the data that may depend on the elapsed time since a specific point in the past.

It's also worth considering whether other variables, such as altitude, land cover, or ocean currents, might be relevant for predicting temperature or other climatic variables. These variables could be important for understanding and predicting local climate patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I should focus on months only, since I don't intend to train on multi year data. I have altitude, land/sea flag data in addition, they had slipped past my head. In total I should be having near 10 features.